# Using update panel to prevent postback of RadUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel, postback

I am trying to use a RadUpload Control, however, on any button click the page postbacks. To get around this I am trying to use a updatePanel and placing the button in the updatePanel, so that only a partial postback occurs.  The reason for this is that the RadUpload Control loses it's value on postback.  I am dynamically creating all the controls, and being a beginner to asp.net and C# this is tricky for me.

Here is the code:

```
Button aButton = new Button();
aButton.ID = newControls[1].ID + "_Button";
aButton.Click += new EventHandler(aButton_Click);
aButton.UseSubmitBehavior = false;

AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = aButton.ID;
trigger.EventName = "Click";

UpdatePanel container = new UpdatePanel();
container.ID = newControls[1].ID + "_Container";
container.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;
container.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
container.Triggers.Add(trigger);
container.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(aButton);

tcControl.Controls.Add(container);

static void aButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

I know i'm probably doing something very wrong haha, but any advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: At what point does that code run?  I would guess that your having a problem with the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  Specifically, dynamically generated controls should always being added during the "PreInit" event.

Comment: This code runs through a method which is called in the Page_Load. Should dynamically created controls be created in the PreInit always?

I am dynamically creating a large number of controls. This small portion of code only occurs when a radupload is created.

Comment: I tried to place the dynamic control generating methods in the PreInit and they don't show up on the page. I am creating them all with unique ID's and placing them in an HTMLTable. This table contains anywhere from 1...n rows, and each row has two cells.  The first cell contains a static label that is dynamically created. The second contains two controls, a dynamically created control of nearly any type, and a label that holds the text from the first control. The visibility of the controls in the second cell alternate, between edit mode(non-label is visible) and non-edit mode(label is visible)

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm not incredibly familiar with creating controls in this fashion, I just know that's a common pitfall people run into.  And yes, dynamically created controls should always be created / recreated in `PreInit` for the most stable performance.  Sorry I wasn't a whole lot of help.  Hopefully someone will come along that can help you out more.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyways (: and ill keep the advice about using the PreInit for future reference for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by completely removing this upload control from the page and instead replacing it with a button that loads an external upload page(just a popup). I was unable to find a solution for what I originally intended, but my current solution is all I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating controls again on postback? If I don't remember bad, controls should be created again on init or preinit so viewstate is loaded into them.

This video http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-to-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-web-page shows something similar, I guess, otherwise on monday I can look for my own code at my pc at work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I am, and I am able to retain the values of all the controls after post back except for with the RadUpload/FileUpload Control.  This is due to security reasons, and I am trying to create a work around for retaining the values because any event that occurs triggers a post back. What I am trying to do above is encapsulate the button to cause only a partial post back on button click so that the entire page does not post back.  Thanks for your input though (:

Comment: OK sorry I missunderstood your problem :S  Anyway why isn't you're code above working? that code looks fine... which are the sympthoms?

Comment: Essentially the only problem is that i'm unable to get a partial postback which affects only the button control :P this is so that the radupload control's value does not get removed. I think that is possible.. :S